# How to use navigation inside ModalBottomSheet in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, webview, navigation

I want to show a Webview inside a ModalBottomSheet. The behavior I want is that the back button should navigate the webview till it can go back. I was able to achieve that using `WillPopScope`.

But this also disables the closing of ModalBottomSheet on tapping outside it in the grey area. How can I achieve both the behaviors?

Comment: Try adding `isDismissible: false` parameter to showModalBottomSheet Function.
You can continue using WillPopScope for WebView Navigation.

Comment: But this will disable the closing of ModalBottomSheet on tapping outside the Widget.